# Need a HTTPS-capable Python XML-RPC server

Tags: python, ssl, https, xml-rpc

I already have a very simple threading XML-RPC server in Python:

```
from SocketServer import ThreadingMixIn
class AsyncXMLRPCServer(ThreadingMixIn, SimpleXMLRPCServer):
    pass

server = AsyncXMLRPCServer(('localhost', 9999))
server.register_instance(some_object())
server.serve_forever()
```

Now I want to make it accessible exclusively over https.  What do I do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The standard library doesn't support HTTPS servers. There is a [Cookbook Recipe](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/496786/) using an OpenSSL module. There is also a [Twisted solution](http://www.etopian.com/portfolio/https-python-xmlrpc-server-w-authentication).

Comment: I had seen that recipe, but thought things may have gotten into the standard library that were not there in 2006 when that recipe was written.  Guess not :-(

Comment: I vote for twisted. You can write nice custom servers with it too - see http://blog.gridspy.co.nz/2009/09/database-meet-realtime-data-logging.html